# complex integral where residue is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

i want to prove that:

$\int_0^{\infty}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}(1-e^{-t})dt=2\sqrt{\pi}$

I noticed that the integral can be written in this form:

$\int_0^{\infty}t^{a-1}R(t)dt$ where $R(t)=\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$

There is a theorem in my book which says that these integrals can be calculated like this:

$\int_0^{\infty}t^{a-1}R(t)dt=\frac{2\pi}{1-e^{i2\pi a}} \sum_j Res[z_j^{a-1}R(z_j)]$

Where $z_j$ its poles, the problem is that the residue of this function is zero which means that the whole integral calculates to zero, which means means im doing something wrong but i can't figure out what. Also the first integral looks a bit like the Gamma function if it's any help maybe the answer lies there.

Comment: Are you required to use that theorem? (If yes, could you cite it exactly please?) Anyway, if $$\int_0^\infty t^{-1/2}e^{-t}~dt\left[=2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}~dx\right]=\sqrt{\pi}$$ is considered known, the given integral reduces to this one using integration by parts.

Comment: Well you solved with a much more clever way, still i dont understand why my approach gives me the wrong result. I don't need to use the theroem but here is what is exactly stated: a)$R(z)$ has no poles on the real positive semi-axis b) $z^aR(z)$ is $0$ for $|z|\rightarrow 0$ and $|z|\rightarrow \infty$ where a is real and a non integer, and the rest of the theorem i covered in my original post

Comment: What if, for our $R$, when checking $|z|\to\infty$, we take *negative real* $z$?

Comment: Why does that cause a problem?

Comment: I think you are right thanks very much